# How to instruct Scala not to upcast abstract type?

Tags: scala, types, abstract-type

Considering Bulldog:

```
trait Animal {
  type Food

  def defaultFood(): Food
}
class Bulldog extends Animal {
  type Food = Steak

  ... implementations ...
}
```

The function `Bulldog.defaultFood()` works just fine for compiler (though my syntax highlighter gave an error, this is no big deal):

```
val bulldog = new Bulldog()
val df: bulldog.Food = bulldog.defaultFood()
```

However if bulldog is enclosed inside another class, all hell break loose:

```
class Kennel(val animal: Animal) {
}
def getSupply(kennel: Kennel): kennel.animal.Food = {
  ... implementation ...
}

val kennel = new Kennel(bulldog)
val df2: bulldog.Food = getSupply(kennel)
```

Scala compiler will throw a compile error:

```
type mismatch;
 found   : Option[kennel.animal.V] where val kennel: Kennel
 required: bulldog.Food
```

Is this feature currently missing in Scala? Is there any way to make it work?

Comment: A question: are you not intending to write `type Food = Steak` in the bulldog implementation, rather than `object Food`?

Comment: sorry my bad, fixed.

Comment: You haven't defined what `getSupply()` _does_, only that it has a return type.

Comment: Yes it is not abstract and should be defined, fixed.
Sorry for the slow response as I haven't had chance to try any of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has a compilation problem - `kennel.animal` is unresolvable since class `Kennel` doesn't expose `animal` as a public field; this is easily resolved by adding `val` in front of `animal`.

What seems to be bothering you though is that `Kennel` has no knowledge about the underlying animal, other than it's an `Animal`. Passing a bulldog is seen as passing some animal.

Try adding some more type info to `Kennel`:

```
class Kennel[A <: Animal](val animal: A) {  }

def getSupply[A <: Animal](kennel: Kennel[A]): kennel.animal.Food

val kennel = new Kennel(bulldog)
val df2: bulldog.Food = getSupply(kennel)
```

Now `Kennel` knows the exact type of `animal` (e.g. `Bulldog`) and `getSupply` is able to return the exact type of food for that animal.

Here's full working code that you can try out:

```
trait Steak {
  override def toString() = "steak"
}

trait Animal {
  type Food
  def defaultFood(): Food
}

class Bulldog extends Animal {
  type Food = Steak
  def defaultFood() = new Steak {}
}

class Kennel[A <: Animal](val animal: A)

object Test extends App {

  def getSupply[A <: Animal](kennel: Kennel[A]): kennel.animal.Food = kennel.animal.defaultFood()

  val bulldog = new Bulldog()
  val kennel = new Kennel(bulldog)
  val df2: bulldog.Food = getSupply(kennel)

  println(df2) // prints "steak"
}
```

Comment: I have a slight spin-off question. Why go to the lengths of doing it like this? Why isn't it enough for the Animal trait to just declare `defaultFood()` method, which returns an instance of another trait, `Food`? And why is it important for the `Kennel` and `getSupply()` to be generic, when the passed parameters will certainly be an implementation of the trait (if the  `Animal` is set as the parameter type, of course)?

Comment: @AleksandarStojadinovic It depends on what you need. I think @tribbloid wants to have `df2` of type `Steak`, which is not just any food, but bulldog's favourite food. Similarly, if you say that the parameter is of type `Animal`, you know that the passed parameter will be an implementation of it, but you don't know which one. You lose the distinction between different animals. By using `A <: Animal` you can refer to exact `A` that was used. This way kennel not only holds "some animal type", but it knows which exact animal type (in our example, `Bulldog`).

Comment: Ok, makes sense, tnx. I guess it is also related from the school of thought you are coming from (or the amount of Java/C# influence you have in you :-) )

Comment: Yeah, I guess :) Of course, if we didn't need `A` later on (which we did; we reused it for defining the type of animal), we would have no benefit of writing the parameter type as `A <: Animal`. Thanks to the subtype polymorphism from OOP, we can always pass any concrete `Animal` (bulldog, rhino, chicken) to this method. But if we want to "capture" that type and use it afterwards, this is how we do it. Java also has similar techniques, just less flexible (especially when you include variance into the story).

Comment: Wow you are sharp, I copied from a case class and forgot to add a val, corrected

Comment: @tribbloid Great! So did you manage to make the whole thing work?

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot.
Though I still think generic type is too verbose and scala compiler should be smart enough to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

Parametric polymorphism (i.e., typeclasses) is a better way to model
this. The main operation here is that you have an animal and you have to
retrieve an instance of its favourite food. Turn this into a typeclass
and provide instances for specific animals and their favourite foods.
E.g.:

```
@annotation.implicitNotFound(
  "Couldn't confirm that ${Animal}'s favourite food is ${Food}")
trait DefaultFood[Animal, Food] { def apply(animal: Animal): Food }
object DefaultFood {
  /** Helper to easily implement typeclass instances. */
  class Impl[Animal, Food](getFood: Animal => Food)
    extends DefaultFood[Animal, Food] {
    override def apply(animal: Animal): Food = getFood(animal)
  }
}

class Bulldog
object Bulldog {
  type Steak = String // Or whatever.

  implicit val defaultFood: DefaultFood[Bulldog, Steak] =
    new DefaultFood.Impl(_ => "Steak")
}

class Kennel[Animal, Food](
  animal: Animal)(implicit defaultFood: DefaultFood[Animal, Food]) {
  def getSupply: Food = defaultFood(animal)
}

object Test {
  val kennel = new Kennel(new Bulldog) // Kennel[Bulldog, Bulldog.Steak]
}
```

This propagates the generic types forward into the `Kennel` class, but
because of Scala's type inference, you don't actually have to spell out
the types. Also the `@implicitNotFound` annotation gives you a nice
compile error message if there's no typeclass instance for a particular
animal and its food.

Note that the `Animal` and `Food` types don't *actually* need to be
animals and foods; that's just the semantics we're using here. If you
look at it in the most generic possible way, this typeclass is actually
just a function of type `A => B` for some `A` and `B`.